# C# Splitting listbox selected item and putting it on label

Tags: c#, split, listbox, label, listboxitem

I want to split the selected `ListBoxItem`, but all it returns is `System.String[]`

In listbox:

- 1|test
- 2|test
- 3|test

  ```
  private void lb_FRIENDS_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string[] text = lb_FRIENDS.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('|').ToString();
     label1.Text = text.ToString();
  }
  ```

  Not sure how to make it say the `ListBoxItem` where I split it from

Comment: Are the items in the list not of type ``string``?

Comment: What do you want get result? for example from "1|test" what do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = "07|00"
string[] result = value.Split('|');

Console.WriteLine(result[0]); //will output 07
Console.WriteLine(result[1]); //will output 00
```

Answer (score 0):

First you splitting by "|" and setting to array of strings, than setting to labels
You can do like this:

```
private void lb_FRIENDS_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Also your sender is selected item here you can cast it like in code below    
    //string[] text=(sender as ListBoxItem).ToString().Split('|');

    string[] text = lb_FRIENDS.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('|');
    label1.Text = text[0].ToString();
    label2.Text = text[1].ToString();
}
```

In your question you setting String to String[] in line below

```
 string[] text = lb_FRIENDS.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('|').ToString();
```

here will be error you can set only

```
 string text = lb_FRIENDS.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('|').ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to split a string into array when you can get the string by using `Substring` method.

```
private void lb_FRIENDS_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string srtItem = lb_FRIENDS.SelectedItem.ToString();
   label1.Text = strItem.Substring(0, strItem.IndexOf("|"));
   label2.Text = strItem.Substring(strItem.IndexOf("|")+1);
}
```